# Some fields are not filled in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hello people of the community, I come with a problem which is a bit "strange" for me. A little context:

I am creating a form for an Exam, which has a question, which is accompanied by the fields, `description`, `iframe`, `image`, the image is optional. These questions in turn will have their field `description`, `iframe`, `image` too.

- For this, what I did was, in the form create an array `question[]` to
  store the fields of that table, as they are `question[description]`,
  `question[iframe]` and `question[image]`
- For the answers apply something similar, a two-dimensional array
  `answers[][]` in one I keep the index of the answer and in the other
  the field, my fields are `answers[][description]`, `answers[][iframe]` and `answers[][image]`
- When you try to insert only the description and video of the
  question, there is no problem. The problem lies in the responses,
  which not all save the fields. On the part of
  `answers[][description]` the first field does save, the second no
  longer, the third does and the fourth does not.
- In `answers[][iframe]` the same thing happens, except that the first
  field does not save, the second does not, the third does not and the
  fourth does.

In the following image the problem is better seen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UDAv.png)

And the pic where you can see the fields of the questions:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoIU8.png)

My model `Question`:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Question extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'description', 'iframe', 'image' ,'exam_id'
    ];

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function Exam()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Exam::class);
    }

    public function answers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Answer::class);
    }
}
```

My model `Answers`:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Answer extends Model
{    
    protected $fillable = [
        'description', 'iframe', 'question_id'
    ];

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function question()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Question::class);
    }
}
```

`QuestionController`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Exam;
use App\Http\Requests\QuestionRequest;
use    Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Question;
use function GuzzleHttp\Promise\all;

class QuestionController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Exam $exam)
    {
        return view('question.create', compact(['exam']));
    }

    public function store(Exam $exam, QuestionRequest $request)
    {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'question.description'  => 'required',
            'question.iframe'       => 'required',
            'answers.*.description' => 'required',
            'answers.*.iframe'      => 'required',
        ]);
        dd($data);

        $question = $exam->questions()->create($data['question']);
        $question->answers()->createMany($data['answers']);

        return redirect('/exams/' . $exam->id);
    }
}
```

I'm using a custom `Request` file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class QuestionRequest extends FormRequest {
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'question.description'  => 'required',
            'question.iframe'       => 'required',
            'answers.*.description' => 'required',
            'answers.*.iframe'      => 'required',
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return[
            'question.description.required' => 'Debes agregar una descripcion al campo Descripcion.',
            'question.iframe.required' => 'Debes agregar el link del video al campo Video Asociado.',
            'answers.*.description.required' => 'Debes agregar una respuesta en el campo Respuesta',
            'answers.*.iframe.required' => 'Debes agregar un video en el campo Video Asociado'
        ];
    }
}
```

My Migrations

`Answers`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateAnswersTable extends Migration{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('answers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->bigInteger('question_id')->unsigned();

            $table->text('description');
            $table->text('iframe');
            $table->text('image')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('question_id')->references('id')->on('questions');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('answers');
    }
}
```

`Questions`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateQuestionsTable extends Migration{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up(){

        Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->bigInteger('exam_id')->unsigned();

            $table->text('description');
            $table->text('iframe');
            $table->text('image')->nullable();

            $table->timestamps(); 

            $table->foreign('exam_id')->references('id')->on('exams');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('questions');
    }
}
```

at the last my view `create.blade.php`:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <span>Crear nueva pregunta</span>
                        <a href="/exams/" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm float-right" onclick="return confirm('Tus datos se perderan ¿Deseas regresar a la pagina principal?')">Regresar</a>
                    </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                           @if($errors->any())
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                    <h6>Por favor, verifica que los campos esten llenos</h6>
                                </div>
                            @endif

                            <form action="/exams/{{ $exam->id }}/questions" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                @CSRF

                                <input hidden name="user_id" value="{{ auth()->user()->id }}">
                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <label for="description">Descripcion de la pregunta *</label>
                                    <textarea name="question[description]" type="text" class="form-control" id="description" aria-describedby="descriptionHelp" placeholder="Inserte la pregunta">{{ old('question.description') }}</textarea>
                                    <small id="descriptionHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Escribe la descripcion de la pregunta.</small>


                                    @if($errors->has('question.description'))
                                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                            {{ $errors->first('question.description') }}
                                        </div>
                                    @endif
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="iframe">Video asociado *</label>
                                    <textarea name="question[iframe]" type="text" class="form-control" id="iframe" aria-describedby="iframeHelp" placeholder="Inserte la URL del video">{{ old('question.iframe') }}</textarea>
                                    <small id="iframeHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Inserta la url del video.</small>

                                    @if($errors->has('question.iframe'))
                                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                            {{  $errors->first('question.iframe') }}
                                        </div>
                                    @endif
                                </div>

                                {{-- <div class="form-group d-flex flex-column">
                                    <label for="image">Imagen asociada</label>
                                    <input name="question[image]" type="file" class="py-2">
                                </div> --}}
                                <hr>

                                <legend>Respuestas</legend>
                                        <span id="choiceHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Por favor ingresa las posibles respuestas.</span>
                                        <br>

                                        <div class="form-group">

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="option1" style="font-size: 17px;">Opcion A</label>
                                                <textarea name="answers[][description]" type="text" class="form-control" id="option1" aria-describedby="optionHelp" placeholder="Inserte la primera respuesta">{{ old('answers.0.description') }}</textarea>
                                            </div>

                                            @if($errors->has('answers.0.description'))
                                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                                    {{ $errors->first('answers.0.description') }}
                                                </div>
                                            @endif

                                           <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="iframe">Video asociado *</label>
                                                <textarea name="answers[][iframe]" class="form-control" id="iframe" aria-describedby="iframeHelp" placeholder="Inserte la URL del video" >{{ old('answers.0.iframe') }}</textarea>
                                            </div>

                                            @if($errors->has('answers.0.iframe'))
                                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                                    {{ $errors->first('answers.0.iframe') }}
                                                </div>
                                            @endif

                                        {{--<div class="form-group">
                                                <input name="image[question]" type="file">

                                            </div> --}}
                                        </div> 

                                        <hr><br>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="option2" style="font-size: 17px;">Opcion B</label>
                                                <textarea name="answers[][description]" type="text" class="form-control" id="option2" aria-describedby="optionHelp" placeholder="Inserte la segunda respuesta" >{{ old('answers.1.description') }}</textarea>

                                            @if($errors->has('answers.1.description'))
                                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                                    {{ $errors->first('answers.1.description') }}
                                                </div>
                                            @endif
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="iframe">Video asociado *</label>
                                            <textarea name="answers[][iframe]" class="form-control" id="iframe" aria-describedby="iframeHelp" placeholder="Inserte la URL del video">{{ old('answers.1.iframe') }}</textarea>

                                            @if($errors->has('answers.1.description'))
                                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                                    {{ $errors->first('answers.1.iframe') }}
                                                </div>
                                            @endif
                                            </div>

                                        {{-- <div class="form-group">
                                                <input name="image[question]" type="file">

                                            </div>  --}}                                       
                                        </div>

                                        <hr><br>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="" style="font-size: 17px;">Opcion C</label>
                                                <textarea name="answers[][description]" type="text" class="form-control" id="option3" aria-describedby="optionHelp" placeholder="Inserte la tercera respuesta">{{ old('answers.2.description') }}</textarea>

                                            @if($errors->has('answers.2.description'))
                                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                                    {{ $errors->first('answers.2.description') }}
                                                </div>
                                            @endif
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="iframe">Video asociado *</label>
                                                <textarea name="answers[][iframe]" class="form-control" id="iframe" aria-describedby="iframeHelp" placeholder="Inserte la URL del video">{{ old('answers.2.iframe') }}</textarea>

                                            @if($errors->has('answers.2.iframe'))
                                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                                    {{ $errors->first('answers.2.iframe') }}
                                                </div>
                                            @endif
                                            </div>

                                    {{--    <div class="form-group">
                                                <input name="image[question]" type="file">
                                            </div> --}}
                                        </div>

                                        <hr><br>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="" style="font-size: 17px;">Opcion D</label>
                                                <textarea name="answers[][description]" type="text" class="form-control" id="option4" aria-describedby="optionHelp" placeholder="Inserte la cuarta respuesta">{{ old('answers.3.description') }}</textarea>

                                            @if($errors->has('answers.3.description'))
                                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                                    {{ $errors->first('answers.3.description') }}
                                                </div>
                                            @endif
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="iframe">Video asociado *</label>
                                                <textarea name="answers[][iframe]" class="form-control" id="iframe" aria-describedby="iframeHelp" placeholder="Inserte la URL del video">{{ old('answers.3.iframe') }}</textarea>

                                            @if($errors->has('answers.3.iframe'))
                                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                                    {{ $errors->first('answers.3.iframe') }}
                                                </div>
                                            @endif
                                            </div>

                                            {{--  <div class="form-group">
                                                <input name="image[question]" type="file">
                                            </div> --}}
                                        </div>
                                    <hr><br>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar pregunta</button>

                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
@endsection
```

Update
Add the dd($data) when i send the form

```
array:4 [▼
  "_token" => "rpKkqpr9zmE7Q1ZN8L9CkQ42HJcDY4oi35aDhAqv"
  "user_id" => "1"
  "question" => array:2 [▼
    "description" => "https://youtu.be/ArMga9b77Fs"
    "iframe" => "https://youtu.be/y2TAeAzeqo4"
  ]
  "answers" => array:8 [▼
    0 => array:1 [▼
      "description" => "weuohqwepqjwe"
    ]
    1 => array:1 [▼
      "iframe" => "https://youtu.be/k7ORQhXN9rQ"
    ]
    2 => array:1 [▼
      "description" => "ouwhdouhqw"
    ]
    3 => array:1 [▼
      "iframe" => "https://youtu.be/1_nHJPGJvIo"
    ]
    4 => array:1 [▼
      "description" => "iuoashdahsoduasd"
    ]
    5 => array:1 [▼
      "iframe" => "https://youtu.be/k7ORQhXN9rQ"
    ]
    6 => array:1 [▼
      "description" => "wiodjoiashd"
    ]
    7 => array:1 [▼
      "iframe" => "https://youtu.be/k7ORQhXN9rQ"
    ]
  ]
]
```

and the pic.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IIL9.png)

Comment: Please can you show the output of `dd($data);` from your controller method.

Comment: sure, i'm update mi questions and add the dd($data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is in your view: the answers array's first index is incremented in each call, that's why you have 8 values for 4 options.

try this code for this view:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <span>Crear nueva pregunta</span>
                        <a href="/exams/" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm float-right" onclick="return confirm('Tus datos se perderan ¿Deseas regresar a la pagina principal?')">Regresar</a>
                    </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                           @if($errors->any())
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                    <h6>Por favor, verifica que los campos esten llenos</h6>
                                </div>
                            @endif

                            <form action="/exams/{{ $exam->id }}/questions" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                @CSRF

                                <input hidden name="user_id" value="{{ auth()->user()->id }}">
                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <label for="description">Descripcion de la pregunta *</label>
                                    <textarea name="question[description]" type="text" class="form-control" id="description" aria-describedby="descriptionHelp" placeholder="Inserte la pregunta">{{ old('question.description') }}</textarea>
                                    <small id="descriptionHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Escribe la descripcion de la pregunta.</small>


                                    @if($errors->has('question.description'))
                                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                            {{ $errors->first('question.description') }}
                                        </div>
                                    @endif
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="iframe">Video asociado *</label>
                                    <textarea name="question[iframe]" type="text" class="form-control" id="iframe" aria-describedby="iframeHelp" placeholder="Inserte la URL del video">{{ old('question.iframe') }}</textarea>
                                    <small id="iframeHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Inserta la url del video.</small>

                                    @if($errors->has('question.iframe'))
                                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                            {{  $errors->first('question.iframe') }}
                                        </div>
                                    @endif
                                </div>

                                {{-- <div class="form-group d-flex flex-column">
                                    <label for="image">Imagen asociada</label>
                                    <input name="question[image]" type="file" class="py-2">
                                </div> --}}
                                <hr>

                                <legend>Respuestas</legend>
                                        <span id="choiceHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Por favor ingresa las posibles respuestas.</span>
                                        <br>
                                        @for ($i = 0, $j = 'A'; $i < 4; $i++, $j++)
                                            <div class="form-group">

                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="option{{ $i }}" style="font-size: 17px;">Opcion {{ $j }}</label>
                                                    <textarea name="answers[$i][description]" type="text" class="form-control" id="option{{ $i }}" aria-describedby="optionHelp" placeholder="Inserte la primera respuesta">{{ old('answers.$i.description') }}</textarea>
                                                </div>

                                                @if($errors->has('answers.$i.description'))
                                                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                                        {{ $errors->first('answers.$i.description') }}
                                                    </div>
                                                @endif

                                               <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="iframe">Video asociado *</label>
                                                    <textarea name="answers[$i][iframe]" class="form-control" id="iframe" aria-describedby="iframeHelp" placeholder="Inserte la URL del video" >{{ old('answers.$i.iframe') }}</textarea>
                                                </div>

                                                @if($errors->has('answers.$i.iframe'))
                                                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                                        {{ $errors->first('answers.$i.iframe') }}
                                                    </div>
                                                @endif

                                            {{--<div class="form-group">
                                                    <input name="image[question]" type="file">

                                                </div> --}}
                                            </div> 

                                            <hr><br>
                                        @endfor

                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar pregunta</button>

                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
@endsection
```